# How to show all division wise total in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I show all division wise separate total?

Example:

I want data like this

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     CARD NO  NAME            CAR NO    DIVISION    DATE      AMOUNT
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    80351   MANWATERTANKER   4454HM    102      2013-9-30   95.000   
    60759   TIPPER           2368BK    102      2013-8-31   77.500  
    64545   MFASIL           3334HG    102      2013-9-30   20.000   
    56565   XYAZ             93F68K    102      2013-8-31   55.000  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    Total                                                   247.500

    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     CARD NO  NAME           CAR NO    DIVISION    DATE      AMOUNT
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     90178  ATEEQ            8931RR    105      2013-7-31   551.000 
     43325  USMAN            6732YY    105      2013-6-30   12.500   
     55598  ALAAM            4631TT    105      2013-7-31   158.000
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    Total                                                   721.500

    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     CARD NO  NAME           CAR NO    DIVISION    DATE      AMOUNT
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     40678  FATHISALIM       1632AM    103      2013-6-30   454.440
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    Total                                                   454.440

   -----------------------------------------------------------------
    AND OVERALL TOTAL                                      1423.440
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and now it is showing like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
CARD NO  NAME            CAR NO    DIVISION    DATE      AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------------
80351   MANWATERTANKER   4454HM    102      2013-9-30   95.000   
60759   TIPPER           2368BK    102      2013-8-31   77.500   
40678   FATHISALIM       1632AM    103      2013-6-30   454.440
90178   ATEEQ            8931RR    105      2013-7-31   551.000
64545   MFASIL           3334HG    102      2013-9-30   20.000   
56565   XYAZ             93F68K    102      2013-8-31   55.000   
43325   USMAN            6732YY    105      2013-6-30   12.500   
55598   ALAAM            4631TT    105      2013-7-31   158.000
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                   1423.440
```

and this is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("car", $con);
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}       
$a=$_POST['from'];
$b=$_POST['to'];


echo "<span  align='center' class='style2'>Report For The Period Of $a to $b</span>"; 
       echo "<div id='non-printable'><table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>CardNo</th> <th>NAME/th><th>CARNO</th><th>Division</th> <th>Date</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>";


 // get results1 from database
      $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fuel where  date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by division ASC");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {   



                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['cardno'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['drivernamefuel'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['carno'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['division'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['amount'] . '</td>';


                echo "</tr>"; 

            //Increment the value of the Total_total variable
            //by the salary value of one row till the while loop finishes

            $Total_amount=$Total_amount+$row['amount'];

    }

   echo "<tr>";
   echo '<td>Total</td>';
   echo '<td></td>';
   echo '<td></td>';
   echo '<td></td>';
   echo '<td></td>';
   echo '<td>' . $Total_amount .'</td>';
   echo "</tr>";  


        // close table>
        echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
echo "<div id='non-printable'><table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr><th>CardNo</th> <th>NAME/th><th>CARNO</th><th>Division</th> <th>Date</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>";

// get results1 from database
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fuel where  date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by division ASC");
$division = null;
$division_total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    if ($division !== null && $row['division'] != $division)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>Total</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $division_total .'</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";

        echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr><th>CardNo</th> <th>NAME</th><th>CARNO</th><th>Division</th> <th>Date</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>";

        $division_total = 0;
    }
    $division = $row['division'];

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['cardno'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['drivernamefuel'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['carno'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['division'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['amount'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

    //Increment the value of the Total_amount variable
    //by the salary value of one row till the while loop finishes
    $division_total += $row['amount'];
    $Total_amount=$Total_amount+$row['amount'];
}

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>Total</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' . $division_total .'</td>';
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr><th>AND OVERALL TOTAL</th> <th></th><th></th><th></th> <th></th><th>". $Total_amount ."</th></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

On a side note I would recommend that you sanitize your query. At least use mysql_real_escape_string(). e.g.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fuel where  date BETWEEN '".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."' AND '".mysql_real_escape_string($b)."' order by division ASC");
```

However binding your parameters is much safer. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: your code is working fine thanks william thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part of your code...

```
echo "<span  align='center' class='style2'>Report For The Period Of $a to $b</span>"; 
echo "<div id='non-printable'><table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>CardNo</th> <th>NAME/th><th>CARNO</th><th>Division</th> <th>Date</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>";

// get results1 from database
$currentdiv = '';
$total_amount = 0.00;
$all_total_amount = 0.00;

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fuel where  monthdate BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by division ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    if(trim(strtolower($row['division'])) != $currentdiv) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>Total</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        sprintf('<td>%.2f</td>', $total_amount);
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr></tr>";
        echo "<tr><th>CardNo</th> <th>NAME/th><th>CARNO</th><th>Division</th> <th>Date</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>";

        $all_total_amount += $total_amount;
        $total_amount = 0.00;
        $currentdiv = trim(strtolower($row['division']));
    }

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['cardno'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['drivernamefuel'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['carno'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['division'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
    sprintf('<td>%.2f</td>', floatval($row['amount']));
    echo "</tr>"; 

    $total_amount += floatval($row['amount']);
}

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>Total</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
sprintf('<td>%.2f</td>', $total_amount);
echo "</tr>";  

$all_total_amount += $total_amount;
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>All Total</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
sprintf('<td>%.2f</td>', $all_total_amount);
echo "</tr>";  

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: i replace your code but amount row is not showing anything and overtotal is also not showing anything